# Win8 app can't login to SharePoint Office365

Tags: sharepoint, winrt-xaml, office365-apps

I am trying to run [this MSDN sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Office-365-Create-Windows-5a88ccfc), and it works against a Office 365 site.

However, when I run it against the SharePoint 2013 cloud implementation in my office, I get an authentication failed error, which is actually an error with the message:

```
 <S:Body xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
- <S:Fault>
- <S:Code>
  <S:Value>S:Sender</S:Value> 
- <S:Subcode>
  <S:Value>wst:FailedAuthentication</S:Value> 
  </S:Subcode>
  </S:Code>
- <S:Reason>
  <S:Text xml:lang="en-US">Authentication Failure</S:Text> 
  </S:Reason>
- <S:Detail>
- <psf:error xmlns:psf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Passport/SoapServices/SOAPFault">
  <psf:value>0x80048821</psf:value> 
- <psf:internalerror>
  <psf:code>0x80047860</psf:code> 
  <psf:text>Direct login to WLID is not allowed for this federated namespace</psf:text> 
  </psf:internalerror>
  </psf:error>
  </S:Detail>
  </S:Fault>
  </S:Body>
```

Any idea if there is some setting done by the IT department blocking me, or is there some change I need to make in my app?

Thank you!

Comment: What's that got to do with winrt-xaml?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old implementation, make sure your re-connect the app to o365 and refresh all tokens to get the latest keys in the configuration file in the win8 app. also, make sure to register the app in o365 AD tenant.

Hope this helps.